# Terraform: helm chart not found in repo but work in cli

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

I've got this problem when using terraform `helm_release` provider:

```
Error: chart "external-dns/external-dns" not found in https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/external-dns repository
```

While it works with helm:

```
helm NAME                               CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION                                       
center/bitnami/external-dns     4.5.5           0.7.6           ExternalDNS is a Kubernetes addon that configur...
center/stable/external-dns      2.20.4          0.7.0           DEPRECATED ExternalDNS is a Kubernetes addon th...
external-dns/external-dns       1.3.2           0.10.0          ExternalDNS synchronizes exposed Kubernetes Ser...
stable/external-dns             2.20.4          0.7.0           DEPRECATED ExternalDNS is a Kubernetes addon th...
holms@debian:~/Dev/contracts/setupad/devops-sdk/terraform/stag/post-infra$ helm repo list
NAME            URL                                           
elastic         https://helm.elastic.co                       
stable          https://charts.helm.sh/stable                 
ingress-nginx   https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx    
center          https://repo.chartcenter.io                   
external-dns    https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/external-dns
```

The terraform script:

```
resource "helm_release" "external-dns" {
  name       = "external-dns"
  repository = "https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/external-dns"
  chart      = "external-dns/external-dns"
  namespace  = "default"

  values = [
    file("charts/external-dns.yaml")
  ]
  depends_on = [kubernetes_secret.cloudflare-api]
```

external-dns.yaml:

```
---
provider: "cloudflare"
domainFilter: "setupad.net"
extraArgs:
    - --cloudflare-proxied
env:
    - name: "CF_API_KEY"
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
            name: cloudflare-api
            key: token
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to `external-dns` rather than `external-dns/external-dns`.

```
resource "helm_release" "external-dns" {
  name       = "external-dns"
  repository = "https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/external-dns"
  chart      = "external-dns"
  namespace  = "default"

  values = [
    file("charts/external-dns.yaml")
  ]
  depends_on = [kubernetes_secret.cloudflare-api]
}
```

Comment: sadly this is not workable on my environment (MacOS + terraform v1.5.5) now